# Facing issue on ChecxBox Checked or not event , Not working propertly

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

**JavaScript code:**

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('chkaddress').checked) {
    $('#DivCommunicationAddress').show();
}
else {
   $('#DivCommunicationAddress').hide();
}
```

**Razor View:**

```
@Html.CustomCheckBoxFor(Employee => Employee.IsActive, new { @class = "ui-checkbox chkaddress" })
@Html.LabelFor(Employee=>Employee.IsActive, "Same As Home Address")
```

When I check the Checkbox, doesn't enter into `if` block. It goes to `else` block only.

Comment: show `#DivCommunicationAddress` in both situation?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('chkaddress')` returns collection. You have to specify specific index with that like:

`document.getElementsByClassName('chkaddress')[0].checked`

Comment: Thank you it works for me. you saved my time thanks.